# how to create a new column conditional on other column by using existing columns in python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` in **python** which looks like this

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({"language1": ["english", "english123", "ingles", "ingles123", "14.0", "13", "french"],
                   "language2": ["englesh", "english123", "ingles", "ingles123", "14", "13", "french"],
                   "language3": ["englesh", "engl", "ingles", "ingles123", "14", "13", "spanish"]})
```

What I would like to do, is replicate this **R** code but in **python**

```
dt[,language4:=ifelse(!language1%in%c("french"),paste0(language2,"_win"),paste0(language3,"_lose"))]
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
dt['language4'] = dt.apply(lambda x: ~x['language1'].isin(['french']), x['language2'] + "_win", x['language3']+"_lose")
```

So i came up with this

```
dt.loc[~dt['language1'].isin(["french"]),'language4'] = surv_dt_sd['language2'] + \
    "_win"
```

but i do not know how to implement the `else` bit in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.where` will work here:

```
dt['language4'] = np.where("french" not in dt['language1'], dt['language2'] + '_win', dt['language2'] + '_lose')
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks ! For my information, is there an alternative with the `~` operator and the `isin` ?

Comment: `~` and `isin` isn't the best fit here because it's essentially a SQL anti-join (e.g. WHERE NOT IN), and `isin` takes as an argument a list or a set. If you had multiple exact values besides "french" that you wanted to negate, you could use `~dt['language1'].isin(['german', 'russian', 'japanese'])` as the first argument to `np.where`, but again that would only work with exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

I can also share the "apply + ifelse" solution:

```
dt['language4'] = dt.apply(lambda x: x['language2'] + "_win" if not('french' in x['language1']) else x['language3']+"_lose", axis=1)
```